# Uncontrollable width / indentation of bars in candlestick ApexChart

Tags: width, candlestick-chart, apexcharts

I'm using **ApexchartJS** library.

Is it possible to set a **candle width** or **indentation** size between separate **candle bars** for the **candlestick** chart?

Now I have overlapping of two bars on top of each other.

Please take a look on **CodePen**:
https://codepen.io/yura_bezhentsev/pen/abOGGZo

This is my options config:

```
const options = {
  series: [{
    data: [
      {
        x: 'First',
        y: [6630, 6660, 6623, 6650]
      },
      {
        x: 'Second',
        y: [6650, 6663, 6623, 6630]
      },
      {
        x: 'Third',
        y: [6630, 6660, 6623, 6650]
      }
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'candlestick',
    height: 400
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'category',
    min: 0,
    max: 4
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in ApexCharts when small number of candles are present.
A small workaround is to set the `tickPlacement` property (you'll lose the ability to zoom though)

```js
xaxis: {
  tickPlacement: 'between'
}
```

Comment: thank you.
Its OK if you don't use annotations. Otherwise, the X-coordinate of annotation will lose.
```{
 x: 4, // will force move to x=0 position
 y: 20,
 marker: {…}
}```

Comment: For some reason this disables zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution.

Just add this under plotOptions:

```
bar: {
columnWidth: 10 //or your required width
}
```

Here please have a look at the full chart options with custom width for candlestick bars:

```
const chartOptions = {
        chart: {
          type: "candlestick",
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            columnWidth: 10,
          },
          candlestick: {
            wick: {
              useFillColor: true,
            },
          },
        },
```